# Is it true that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ x_n\geq x_{n+1}$ for any $n\geq N$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let ${(x_n)}_n$ a sequence of strictly positive  real numbers who is convergent whith limit $0$.

Is it true that there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ x_n\geq x_{n+1}$ for any $n\geq N$?

I think that it's true because in the contrary case I can construct an strictly increasing subsequence that converges to $0$ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: "I think that it's true because in the contrary case I can construct an strictly increasing subsequence that converges to $0$" > No, you cannot: the negation of monotone decreasing does not imply the existence of a monotone increasing subsequence.

Comment: Note that "not decreasing" $\neq$ "increasing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $x_n=1/n$ for $n$ odd, and $x_n=2/n$ for $n$ even. This still converges to 0 but bounces around.

However, what is true is that you can always find a monotonic *subsequence* of $x_n$ that converges to $0$. With the same example as above, you could use $y_n:=x_{2n}$. The proof of this fact is closer to your intuition: if $x_n$ converges to 0 and is non-negative, then for any $x_i$ you should be able to find an $x_j$ with $x_j<x_i$ and $j>i$. Repeating this process will generate monotonic subsequences.

Also, be careful with your negations. If you can't find such an $N$ that makes $x_n\geq x_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq N$, that doesn't imply you can construct a strictly increasing sequence. It just means that you can construct a sequence that *occasionally* increases.

Answer (score 2):

How about $1/2$, $1$, $1/4$, $1/3$, $1/6$, $1/5$, $1/8$, $1/7,\ldots$?